# Laravel Login form refuses right login credentials

Tags: authentication, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I'm confused on what could be the problem with this code. It has worked in a test environent but refused to work now. My implementation is for user reation which goes thus: 
Registration page (with a confirmation code sent to the email confirmation) -> Email ( for confirmation and click on the link to return the login page) -> Login page (for the user to login with his credentials). Everythng goes on smoothing until the login in which when I input the login username/email and password it sees it as not matching hixh I'm very sure it matches because I use copy and paste. 
Controller:

```
public function store(UserRequest $userRequest)
    {
        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);

        $users = new User;
        $users->firstname             = $userRequest->firstname;
        $users->lastname              = $userRequest->lastname;
        $users->email                 = $userRequest->email;
        $users->username              = $userRequest->username;
        $users->password              = $userRequest->password;
        $users->confirmation_code     = $confirmation_code;

        Mail::send('email.verify', ['users' => $users, 'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code ], 

            function ($message) use ($users) {

            $message->from('members@schoolproject.com', 'School Project Member');
            $message->to($users->email, $users->firstname)->subject('Registration process Message!');
        });

        $users->save();
       // return redirect()->route('index');
        return redirect()->action('UserController@index')->with('message', 'You have done successfully');
    }


    public function confirm($confirmation_code)
    {
        if( ! $confirmation_code)
        {
            throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
        }

        $users = User::whereConfirmationCode($confirmation_code)->first();

        if ( ! $users)
        {
            throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
        }

        $users->confirmed = 1;
        $users->confirmation_code = null;
        $users->save();

        //Flash::message('You have successfully verified your account.');
        //return redirect()->route('users.index');
        //return view('userpages.login');
        return redirect()->action('DashboardController@login');
    }


    public function login(Request $request){

        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
                return redirect()->route('details')->with('message', 'You have successfully logged in');
        } 

        elseif (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
                return redirect()->route('details')->with('message', 'You have successfully logged in');
        } 

        else {
            return redirect('login')
            ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination is not correct')
            ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Login form:

## Login

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
{!! Form::token() !!}

    {!! Form::label('username', 'Username') !!}<br />
    {!! Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) !!} <br />

    {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}<br />
    {!! Form::password('password') !!} <br />

    {!! Form::submit('Login') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: whats your error message dude

Comment: Sorry for the delay. No error.thrown

Comment: so it simply tells username and password doesnt match?

Comment: you making custom login?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom login. ant it works perfectly on the test environment. I'm surprised it's not working now.